# Debian - ifconfig not showing wlan0

Tags: linux, debian, wifi

I have Debian installed on my laptop (T440s). I've installed the iwlwifi drivers but Wifi does not work. `ifconfig -a` only shows `eth0` and `lo`. What should I do? Also, how do I adjust brightness?

Comment: Are you sure the device is enabled? `ifconfig wlan0 up`

Comment: @QuaxtonHale `ifconfig -a` shows _all_ devices including those that are not up.

Comment: Have you installed the wireless card firmware? Nowadays, it is common to have cards which won't work unless you have external firmware. In Debian, this firmware is part of the `non-free` packages (because it's not free as in freedom). According to the [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi), you need to install the package `firmware-iwlwifi` after adding non-free to the list of package sources. Have you already tried this? (After this, you still need to restart the driver, "rmmod iwlwifi; modprobe iwlwifi".)

Comment: Looks like there was some error or that the driver didn't pick up the wireless device. Look at the output of dmesg: if all is well you will see a line from the driver claiming the device, otherwise you'll see some error messages (quite possible complaining about a lack of firmware, as above)

Comment: Lenovo often changes wifi cards IDs in order to whitelist hardware...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you installed the driver? In Linux, drivers are treated as kernel modules and need to be loaded as such. After downloading the driver via you distribution's package manager, it must be loaded with the `modprobe` command.

First, download the driver:

```
sudo apt-get install iwlwifi-firmware
```

Then unload the conflicting modules

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

or, if the have been unloaded, and the iwlwifi module has been detetcted automatically:

```
modprobe -r iwlwifi
```

Next, load the iwlwifi module:

```
modprobe iwlwifi
```

That should be it!

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi

Comment: the needed driver is `iwlwifi`  ( intel card) , the `wl` module isn't the right driver.

Answer (score 0):

To manage wireless interface you can use iwconfig

Check here for the [list](http://www.wirelessdefence.org/Contents/LinuxWirelessCommands.htm#iwconfig%20Commands) of commands, related to WiFi

Comment: Wireless cards should still be listed in ifconfig, as they are network interfaces.

Comment: As far as I remember some time a go it do not show

Comment: What card is it `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`